# Reading GeoJSON file and querying Nominatim?

Tags: python, geojson, nominatim

I need to loop through a GeoJSON file, where for each "feature", find the city where the track started:

```
with open('input.geojson') as f:
    gj = geojson.load(f)

for track in gj['features']:
    #OK
    print track['geometry']['coordinates'][0]

    #How to query Nominatim to find the city that lat,lon belongs to?

    #Next step : edit 'name' in gj

with open('dump.geojson', 'w') as f:
   dump(gj, f, indent=2)
```

Would someone have some code handy?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using [Geopy](https://github.com/geopy/geopy).

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim

geolocator = Nominatim(user_agent='my_app')

with open('input.geojson') as f:
    geojson = json.load(f)

for i, track in enumerate(geojson['features']):
    lat, lon = track['geometry']['coordinates'][0]
    location = geolocator.reverse((lat, lon))
    # full address as returned by Nominatim
    address = location.address
    # city or country
    city = location.raw['address']['city']
    country = location.raw['address']['country']
    # update geojson
    geojson['features'][i]['properties']['name'] = city

with open('dump.geojson', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(geojson, f, indent=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Reverse Geocoding** as in below example:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Example

**1) XML response:**
**Request:**

```
 https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=xml&lat=52.5487429714954&lon=-1.81602098644987&zoom=18&addressdetails=1
```

**Result:**

```
 <reversegeocode timestamp="Fri, 06 Nov 09 16:33:54 +0000" querystring="...">
    <result place_id="1620612" osm_type="node" osm_id="452010817">
      135, Pilkington Avenue, Wylde Green, City of Birmingham, West Midlands (county), B72, United Kingdom
    </result>
    <addressparts>
      <house_number>135</house_number>
      <road>Pilkington Avenue</road>
      <village>Wylde Green</village>
      <town>Sutton Coldfield</town>
      <city>City of Birmingham</city>
      <county>West Midlands (county)</county>
      <postcode>B72</postcode>
      <country>United Kingdom</country>
      <country_code>gb</country_code>
    </addressparts>   
  </reversegeocode>
```

**Reference:**
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Example

**2) JSON response:**
**Request:**
https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=-34.44076&lon=-58.70521

**Response:**

```
{
  "place_id":"134140761",
  "licence":"Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. http:\/\/www.openstreetmap.org\/copyright",
  "osm_type":"way",
  "osm_id":"280940520",
"lat":"-34.4391708",
  "lon":"-58.7064573",
  "place_rank":"26",
  "category":"highway",
  "type":"motorway",
  "importance":"0.1",
  "addresstype":"road",
  "display_name":"Autopista Pedro Eugenio Aramburu, El Triángulo, Partido de Malvinas Argentinas, Buenos Aires, 1.619, Argentina",
  "name":"Autopista Pedro Eugenio Aramburu",
  "address":{
    "road":"Autopista Pedro Eugenio Aramburu",
    "village":"El Triángulo",
    "state_district":"Partido de Malvinas Argentinas",
    "state":"Buenos Aires",
    "postcode":"1.619",
    "country":"Argentina",
    "country_code":"ar"
  },
  "boundingbox":["-34.44159","-34.4370994","-58.7086067","-58.7044712"]
}
```

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Example_with_format.3Djsonv2